Which statistical test should I use
My data does not follow a normal distribution, is not linear, and there are variables with repeated measurements (temperature, humidity, phenology) and variables measured only once (DBH, age, total height, ...). Now, I want to know which of these variables most influence my dependent variable, and I am stuck. Can you please advise me? I am still a bit of a beginner.

No regression model requires that any variable be normally distributed. OLS regression assumes the errors are normally distributed. Also, data cannot be linear or nonlinear, that's a function of models. And the question "which variable most influences my DV?" is a bit vexed, too. // Please describe your situation in more detail. What (or who) are you measuring? How are you measuring each variable? What is your DV? What is your sample size? Why are some variables repeated?

I have 54 samples. My dependent variable is resin yield measured in grams every week for 11 weeks. Temperature, humidity, and phenology were also measured every week for 11 weeks. DBH, total height, stem height, and age were measured only once during these 11 weeks. And what I mean is that none of the relationships between the variables are linear.

Look into generalized additive mixed effect models (GAMM).
